# How to display HTML file at root -- cloudflare pages

Tags: html, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I am trying to create a simple HTML site using Cloudflare workers. Literally just serving raw HTML loaded from my Github repo. I however cant figure out how to have an HTML file at the root.

I want to be able to go to:

```
https://example.org/
```

and load the file.

Right now what I have had to do is just enter a redirect from the root to `/home.html`

Does anybody know how to set this up?

Many thanks!

Comment: Any reason you haven't named it with the standard `index.html` and saved yourself the headache of configuring a symlink or forwarding to the proper URL?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to configure an `index.html` file. Should have seen that one.